"It never works" vs "It better work"
I'm trying to get a better understanding on when to add an "s" at the end of a present tense verb when the 3rd person is used.
I'm aware modal verbs such as should/would/can make it so that it doesn't take the "s". However I'm a little bit more confused when it comes to words such as "better" or "never" as I always see the "s" with "never" but not with "better".
What is the rule there?

I would say that "had better" is modal.

Never is just an adverb and doesn't affect the subject-verb agreement
of the sentence: It never works.
Had better (usually contracted to 'd better in informal situations) is different.
Cambridge Dictionary defines had better:

We use had better to refer to the present or the future, to talk about actions we think people should do or which are desirable in a specific situation. The verb form is always had, not have. We normally shorten it to ’ d better in informal situations. It is followed by the infinitive without to :


The democratic movement had better concentrate on the immediate issues of the economy and security.

We should say It'd better work or It had better work, not It better work.

Perhaps it's worth noting that in such structures the verb is an infinitive, not a present tense. That's why there's no -s ending. It's the same general structure as It must work, or It should work. Also, I'm not so sure that It better work is always wrong. Certainly in casual speech that seems natural to me, probably because of the challenge in pronouncing the double consonant of It'd.

I agree that it better work is often seen in speech and writing. I think it's even less formal than it'd better, though.

We also use best in much the same way, except that we obviously never include auxiliary had / have in things like You best go now, You best follow orders,...

I agree that best can also be used in that way, but I think you can include had with it as well! Eg, You had best go. This had best construction is also mentioned at the asker's Cambridge Dictionary link.

Thanks, @Peter Kirkpatrick and Wyatt Carpenter.  It better work is informal and its use is probably in informal conversations. Yes, work is a bare infinitive here.

I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote we obviously never include auxiliary had / have in things like this. There are many published written instances of You had best go... - often contracted to You'd best... today. It's not necessarily "informal", and for Victorians, the uncontracted version was actually quite "formal, literary".

@PeterKirkpatrick that's because in (rapid) speech we frequently drop schwas, so "it'd" becomes pronounced identically to "it". It's a similar error to writing "should of done it" rather than "should've done it" because the two would be pronounced identically in speech
